# Replace \\ with \ 

Tags: c#, active-directory

When I sync data from Active directory, and any object attributes have reserve character it escape it by prefix '\' for example :Hello,Adams it will escape it Hello\,Adams.

And in code it show me Hello\,Adams.

I tried it to replace by doing `mystring.Replace("\\",@"\");`

but it not worked.

Any Idea?

Comment: What are you trying to get for a result?  Also don't forget that the mystring.Replace has to be assigned to where you want the updated string to be set as the String class is immutable.

Comment: are you assigning it to variable?? like mystring = mystring.Replace("\\","\") Also remove @ and try.

Comment: @BreakHead: your question is a little confusing.  The subject makes it sound like you want to replace \\ with \, but the example makes it sound like you want to remove the \ completely.  Which are you trying to do?

Comment: @JB King yes I am assigning it to variable.

Comment: @Emaad Ali you can't write "\"

Comment: Thats strange its working on my side, i have code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"\\"` is `@"\"`.

You want to try:

`mystring.Replace(@"\\",@"\");`

Answer (score 6):

You are replacing backslashes with the same character.  Try this:

```
mystring.Replace("\\", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're replacing \ with \ here. That'll do about nothing.

Try this:

```
mystring = mystring.Replace(@"\", "");
```

The @ sign indicates a string literal, more info [here](http://www.kowitz.net/archive/2007/03/06/the-c-string-literal). If you use that, you won't have to escape characters. The following code does the same:

```
mystring = mystring.Replace("\\", "");
```

You see that you have to escape the backslash character with another backslash, since the backslash character is the escape character.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
string.Replace(@"\", "");
```

.

Answer (score 1):

try this. it works

```
(@"sample\,text").Replace(@"\", string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

From here:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace

You must assign the result of the operation to a new string.

Also, you need to have the @ on both strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
string mystring = @"Hello\,Adams";
string answer=mystring.Replace("\\",string.Empty);
//or
string answer=mystring.Replace("\\","");
```

will work.